# Use fitted value from regression on subset of features as independent variable

Tags: logistic, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction

I am working with a relatively large data set with 2K columns and many variables can be grouped together (a logistic regression). So I am thinking can I use fitted value from regression on subset of features as independent variable?.

For example
Instead of:
Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + Z1 + Z2 + Z3

Can I use Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 and Y ~ Z1 + Z2 + Z3

then use the fitted value Y1 and Y2 from those two models to do: Y ~ Y1 + Y2

Please correct me if there is any issue with this method. Thanks!

Comment: What are Y1 and Y2?

Comment: Good point! My mistake, Y1 and Y2 should be the fitted value of each sub-model

Comment: *If* the X's and Z's are independent, this might work. If there's dependence, this might not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are saying is that you have two types of columns... type 1 and type 2.  You have a target variable $y$ to estimate.  What you are suggesting to do is to estimate $y_1$ with the type 1 columns, then $y_2$ with the type 2 columns, and finally estimate $y$ as a function of $\hat y_1$ and $\hat y_2$.

Although this is certainly possible, you don't indicate why would you be interested in doing this.   If you want to do dimensionality reduction, I would recommend you to do PCA instead, and then regress $y$ into the principal components.

The problem of your approach is that you are introducing unnecessary noise for the estimation of the parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One follow up question if you don't mind: What is the difference between using PCA, LDA and simply regression? I tried both LDA and regression and found that the regression result has higher correlation with response variable.